# Keeping variable from changing on another scene load

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, game-engine

I'm new to unity and i'm trying to load scenes based on items collected.
Problem is that the counter is not counting my acquired items.
I'm using `OnTriggerEnter2D()` to trigger the event; Below is the snippet:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        collectionNumber += 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);
        if (collectionNumber == 1)
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.Find("Acquired_Items").GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true); 
            qiCollector.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (collectionNumber == 2)
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.Find("Acquired_Items").GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            qiCollector.gameObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (collectionNumber == 3)
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.Find("Acquired_Items").GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            qiCollector.gameObject.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("All Items Collected !!");
        }

        cN.text = "Collection Number " + collectionNumber.ToString();
    }
}
```

Whenever a new scene is loaded this script is loaded because it is on my quest item. And for every scene there is a quest item. So what I want to do is basically keep track of my `collectionNumber`, but it resets to `0`.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: you can read about singleton

Comment: You can save data to singleton and load as new scene starting

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrey ! Singleton did work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

**First method**:
Don't allow your object to be destroyed on scene load
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

```
public static void DontDestroyOnLoad(Object target);
```

Above code will prevent destroying your GameObject and its components from getting destroyed when loading a new scene, thus your script values

**Second Method**:
Write out your only value into a player pref
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

```
// How to save the value
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CollectionNumber", collectionNumber);
// How to get that value
collectionNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CollectionNumber", 0);
```

**Third method**:
Implement a saving mechanism:
In your case i would not suggest this

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Menyus I'll try these methods and use the efficient one , but for now Singleton is doing good for me 

Comment: Would recommend PlayerPrefs but yes, choose what you are more comfortable with.

Comment: For the sake of full answer, there could be a fourth method using a static class with static members.

Comment: He might wanna derive from monobehaviour